Consequences of definition of scalar product
Definition: Let  $V$ be a vector space over the field $K=\mathbb{R}$ (or over $K=\mathbb{C})$. The scalar product on $V$ is a function $V\times V\to K,$ denoted by $(x,y)\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle$, which satisfies the following properties:
For all $x,y,z\in V$ and $\alpha\in K$,

$\langle x,y \rangle = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$

$\langle x,y+z\rangle =\langle x,y\rangle +\langle x,z\rangle$

$ \langle \alpha x,y\rangle =\alpha\langle x,y\rangle$

$\langle x,x\rangle\geq 0$, with equality iff $x=0$.



I needed to prove some consequences of the definition:
• $\langle x+y,z \rangle=\langle x,z\rangle +\langle y,z\rangle$
We have $$\langle x+y,z \rangle= \overline {\langle z,x+y\rangle}=\overline{\langle z,x \rangle +\langle z,y\rangle}=\langle x,z\rangle +\langle y,z\rangle.$$
• $\langle 0,x\rangle=\langle x,0\rangle =0$.
We have $$\langle 0,x\rangle =\langle 0x,x\rangle= 0\langle x,x\rangle=0\overline{\langle x,x\rangle}=\overline{\langle 0x,x\rangle}=\overline {\langle 0,x\rangle}=\langle x,0\rangle,$$ but notice that $0\langle x,x\rangle=0.$
•If $y=-x$, then $\langle 0,z\rangle= \langle x,z\rangle +\langle -x,z\rangle.$
We have $$\langle 0,z\rangle =\langle x+-x, z\rangle =\langle x,z\rangle +\langle -x,z\rangle.$$ Here I used the first consequence.
Are my solutions correct?

For the first one, I would have just added the line
$$\overline{\langle z,x\rangle+\langle z,y\rangle}=\overline{\langle z,x\rangle}+\overline{\langle z,y\rangle}$$
The second one is okay and for the third one, do you mean
$$\langle 0,z\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle+\langle y,z\rangle$$
in that case, it is okay to use the first part as you did.
Hope this helps. :)

Yes, thank you! I actually wrote  that line in my notebook, but I skipped it when writing the question
